# Best method to sort a nested array based on multiple nested values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to determine the most economical combination of [8, 10, 12] to equal a given number (between 8 and 60) and store that combination in a variable for later use. Numbers can repeat (8+8=16, 10+10=20, etc). The given number will always be even. It is acceptable for combinations to exceed the given number by 2 (eg given number is 14, acceptable combination would be 8+8).

I can calculate the combinations and store them in a nested array. I can then sort the array on one of the indices which will solve the problem in many cases. I've tried some conditional sorting on the array but the results have been inconsistent.

My code...

```
var combo = (num) => {
        var arr = [];
        let units = [8, 10, 12];
        for (let i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
            arr.push([units[i],Math.floor(num / units[i]),num%units[i]]);
            } 
            console.log(arr);
    }; 


//combo(24);
//returns
//[[8, 3, 0],[10, 2, 4],[12, 2, 0]]
```

While both the first and third nested arrays are correct, the third would be the most economical and desired result.

```
//combo(28)
//returns
//[[8, 3, 4],[10, 2, 8],[12, 2, 4]]
```

In this case, the second array is the desired result

```
//combo(42)
//returns
//[[8, 5, 2],[10, 4, 2],[12, 3, 6]]
```

In this case, the third array is the desired result as replacing the 6 with an 8 later will exceed the given num by 2 - an acceptable result.

My goal is to first isolate the desired result and store it in a separate variable OR in a consistent location within the array (through sorting) for use later. I've discovered 1000 ways not to do this but, a successful method escapes me. I would classify my javascript experience as 'high-beginner' or 'low-intermediate' as I'm learning in my spare time. I may be approaching this from the wrong direction so any guidance is greatly appreciated. Hopefully, my description of the problem makes sense.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "most economical"?

Comment: "Most economical" was probably a bad choice of words on my part. Index 1 of any of the sub-arrays represents a quantity. In the example 'combo(24)', 8 (index 0) * 3 (index 1) is 24 but 12 * 2 also equals 24. [12, 2, 0] is more economical. Thanks for asking and I hope that clarifies.

Comment: No, you just repeated what you had already said. I'm afraid you won't be able to solve this, or at least I won't, unless you can clearly state what you mean by economical. What makes 12 * 2 more economical, than 8 * 3?

Comment: Fair point. 8, 10 and 12 represent lengths of wood. Num represents an overall length. The 'most economical' solution is the one that requires the fewest lengths to achieve the over all length. 2 lengths of 12 is more economical than 3 lengths of 8 (as related to quantity). This economy becomes more important as num increases eg: 48(num) = 6 at 8 or  4 at 10 + 1 at 8 or 4 at 12 - 4 at 12 being the most economical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, the optimal solution is the one with the smallest factor and the remainder being zero, that is trivial.

If none such solution is found, I think what you want is to first sort on the second field descending (least lengths) and then on the percentage of the remainder of the full length ascending in order to minimize cutoff. Consider:

```
var combo = (length) => {
    var optimals    = [];
    var suboptimals = [];

    [8, 10, 12].forEach( (unit) => {
        let lengths = Math.floor(length / unit);
        let remainder = length % unit;
        let fraction  = remainder / unit ;

        if ( remainder == 0 )
            optimals.push( [unit, lengths] );
        else
            suboptimals.push( [unit, lengths, remainder, fraction] );
    } );

    // This only works as long as the original input list is sorted ascending
    // Because then we know the most optimal solution must be the one 
    // with the biggest factor so we can simply return the last solution
    if ( optimals.length > 0 )
        return optimals[ optimals.length - 1 ];

    // Else we sort the suboptimals
    suboptimals.sort( (a, b) => {
        return a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : // First on # of lengths descending
               a[1] > b[1] ?  1 : 
               a[3] > b[3] ? -1 : // Then on fraction ascending
               a[3] < b[3] ?  1 : 
               0;
      });  

    return suboptimals[0];
}; 

console.log( combo(24) );
console.log( combo(28) );
console.log( combo(42) );
```

Prints:

```
> Array [12, 2]
> Array [10, 2, 8, 0.8]
> Array [12, 3, 6, 0.5]
```

Comment: That's great Holli! I really appreciate your help and input. This not only helps solve this problem but I have also learned a lot and I truly appreciate your time in answering my question! In the future, I'll be more clear on the details! Thanks again!